# Filter collection by attribute Set

Tags: php, magento

How would one filter collection by attribute set name

I am trying as following, but its not working

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_name',"Quantity Television Parts");
```

Thank You

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is how i end up doing.

I looked up id of the attribute-set-name in the table "eav_attribute_set" table and used following filter:

```
$products->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id','33');
```

Comment: You can also find the attribute set id in the backend : just open the attribute set edit page and read the URL : the number just after "id/" is the attribute set ID.

Answer (score 3):

We can filter the collection by attribute set using:

```
addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id','attribute set id here');
```

suppose your attribute set id is 10.

For example

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' =>1))

           ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id','10')
           ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```